# Transformer - Different Inference Results in a generation loop

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to implement a Transformer model from scratch in PyTorch. I used this blog post as reference: https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/building-a-transformer-with-py-torch. When comparing the implementation on the website to the one from the "Attention is all you Need" it seems to be correct in my opinion. (Note: for testing purposes I used the exact same code as on the website, hence I won't include it here to keep things more readable)

Everything works as expected, I can train the model and I see the loss decreasing. However, when using the model for inference in a generation loop and supplying the `tgt` matrix with one character at a time (see my generation loop below) I see different results compared to supplying the whole `tgt` matrix at once.

My Inference Generation Loop:

```py
start_char = 6 # Character idx for start sequence (<SOS>)
stop_char = 2 # Character idx for stop sequence (<EOS>)

sample_idx = 0 # Choose a random sample to predict
tgt_data = torch.tensor([[start_char]]) # Init tgt with start character

keep_predicting = True
while keep_predicting:
    
    # Get output from transformer and return index of maximum value
    transformer_out = transformer(src_data[sample_idx].unsqueeze(0), tgt_data)
     
    # Get index of highest value
    max_idx = torch.argmax(transformer_out, dim=-1)
    
    # Append value to tgt_data
    tgt_data = torch.concat((tgt_data, max_idx[:,-1].unsqueeze(0)), dim=1)
    
    # Stop the generation loop once stop char has been reached
    if(max_idx[0, -1] == stop_char):
        keep_predicting = False
```

This gives me different results than evaluating the transformer without a generation loop as below:

```py
transformer.eval()

output = transformer(src[sample_idx].unsqueeze(0), tgt[sample_idx, :-1].unsqueeze(0))
indx_output = torch.argmax(output, dim=-1)
```

Am I missing something? In theory I'd think that both methods should provide me with similar results. Per my understanding the no-peak mask in the decoder ensures that the Transformer has no advantage when it sees the full tgt data and cannot attend to positions in the future, which should ensure that it provides correct results.

However the no peak mask does not affect the "Add & Norm" block where the Masked Multi-Head Attention results are added up to the embeddings of the outputs. Could this be the explanation for my results? If this is the case - shouldn't the output of the generation loop be considered a much more valuable error / loss metric than the loss / error during training with the whole `tgt` (or output) supplied (as this is what's relevant when generating actual predictions)?

I tried executing the code from https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/building-a-transformer-with-py-torch with the generation loop and without above and get different results from them, even though I'd expect them to be roughly the same.

Comment: Can you provide a specific reproducible example?

Comment: How are you doing "inference" in the second version, when you are already supplying a full `tgt` array you are presumably getting from somewhere else?